# Submit button and input have different widths in Boostrap 4

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4, submit

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I can't seem to make the submit button the same size as the input. I tried different combinations but every time the button ends up being wider than the input. I'm thinking that's maybe some Bootstrap default CSS for buttons that I don't know about? Thank you!

This is my code: `

```html
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row justify-content-center"> 

            <div class="col-sm-6 bg-warning p-2 d-flex justify-content-center" >

                <form action="" method="POST" class="p-5 m-1 bg-danger col-8"> 

                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-9 col-xl-8">
                            <label for="InputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="userEmail" required>
                            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else</small>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 

                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center"> 
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-9 col-xl-8">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="userPass" required>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 

                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-9 col-xl-8" name="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>

            </form> <!-- end of form -->
        </div> <!-- end of column -->
    </div>  <!-- end of row -->
</div> <!-- end of container -->

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First solution**

The reason was your input fields are inside `col` class and columns class are getting `padding-right:15px` and `padding-left:15px` from bootstrap plugin.

You can add class to the column `padding_0` something like this

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-9 col-xl-8 padding_0">
```

and add style `.padding_0{padding-right:0;padding-left:0;}`

**Second solution**

You are adding the `col-*` to the button.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-9 col-xl-8" name="submit">Submit</button>
 </div>
```

Make a parent div something like below code and add `col-*` class to that div. Also set `width:100%` to the button.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-9 col-xl-8">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%;">Submit</button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**Snippet for second solution**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-sm-6 bg-warning p-2 d-flex justify-content-center">

        <form action="" method="POST" class="p-5 m-1 bg-danger col-8">

          <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-9 col-xl-8">
              <label for="InputEmail1">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="userEmail" required>
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else</small>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-9 col-xl-8">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="userPass" required>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row justify-content-center form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-9 col-xl-8">
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%;">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
        <!-- end of form -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of column -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of row -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of container -->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Both methods worked but I used the second for the sake of being consistent with the way I wrote the code.

Comment: Gland to help you.